# where Environment variables for python are saved

Tags: python, django, environment-variables

I know to set an environment variable in python is to use os.environ['API_USER'] but where this variable is saved, I supposed this environment variable is saved in .env file but it wasn't.

on the console to retrieve all the environment variables use command: os.environ
but don't know where are saved. 
need your help, Thanks!

Comment: Environment variables are specific to each process, on linux they can be accesses in `/proc`. Why do you need to know where they are saved?

Comment: because I am working on a project with Django, and need to save environment variable in the .env file, so after typing os.environ['API_USER'] in the shell I supposed the .env will be updated with the API_USER but it wasn't , so i wonder where it is saved

Comment: If API_USER is a constant why do you not already have it as an environment variable?

Comment: yes it is constant, I was just debugging because when I try to retrieve it in the settings.py os.environ.get('API_USER') also it is in the .env file !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Environment variables live in the memory, not on the disk. People usually save environment variables in files only for not having to do the same exporting of them by hand repetitively.

Also note that, environment variables are properties of operating system processes, and the process specific ones are passed on to all of the subprocesses of that process.

So when you run `os.environ`, it shows the environment variables and their values belonging to the `python` process (the executable that is being executed).

Comment: so the meaning of what you said if the webserver process of Django is running and I opened the Python shell and type os.environ all the Environment variables for that process will be listed?

Comment: @Flupper When you open the Python shell that's a new `python` process that is running, which has no relation to the Django webserver running in any way. And it's environment is totally different from Django's (unless you have exported the same set of environment varaiables while they start, and even then some environment variables would be different).

Comment: when I listed the environment variables of python shell process why some variables relating to my Django project appears like Tz: timezone DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE PS1 . ?!

Comment: @Flupper Because you've `export`-ed them from the shell and then from the same shell you've open `python`. (See the subprocess rule on my answer).

Comment: I got it, Thank you for your clarification

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to use a `.env` file to store environment variables, using the `python-dotenv` package. Documentation [can be found here](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/)

A simple example would be to create a `.env` file with the contents:

```
API_USER=username
```

Then, in your code you can use:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
```

Note that without specifying a path to the `.env` file it assumes it is in the same directory. For a more detailed example on specifying a path, see the documentation.

You can then access the environment variable using `os.getenv('API_USER')`

Comment: thanks for sharing with me this package, I gonna use it